# Delete content of one array out of an other PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have the following to Arrays
$a = 1,2,3,4,5
$b = 2,3

now, can i delete the content of $b out of $a so that the output for $a would be:
1,4,5

Thanks in advance
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare the collections and save the results back to $a:

```
$a = 1,2,3,4,5
$b = 2,3

$a = compare $a $b -PassThru
$a

1
4
5
```

Comment: thanks that worked! But would it also be possible with words?